# Create a 3D curve in R

Tags: r, 3d

I have a data set that looks like this, where the first row is the time to maturity and the first column is the dates and the rest of the data is the yields to maturity

And im trying to have an output that looks like this

[image: Picture 2]

I have tried this code

```
dput(yields)
x = yields[,1]
y = yields[,1]
z.matrix = matrix(nrow=nrow(yield),ncol=ncol(yield)-1)
for(i in 2:nrow(yields)){
  for(j in 2:(ncol(yields))-1){
    z.matrix[i,j] = yield[i,j+1]
  }
}
lines3D(x, y, z.matrix)
```

And its giving me the error that: Error in scatter3D(x, y, z, type = "l") : 'z' should have same length as 'x'

**Data**

```
yield <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(1186444800, 1186531200, 1186704000, 
1186963200, 1187049600, 1187136000, 1187222400, 1187308800, 1187568000, 
1187654400, 1187740800, 1187827200, 1187913600, 1188172800, 1188259200, 
1188345600, 1188432000, 1188518400), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = ""), X1 = c(9.064326, 8.969148, 9.128214, 9.084583, 
9.088544, 9.080606, 9.0806, 9.116042, 9.080283, 9.108036, 9.084211, 
9.052445, 9.025128, 8.985457, 9.001349, 9.041063, 9.10459, 9.1453
), X2 = c(9.085159, 8.974176, 9.12059, 9.069715, 9.074333, 9.065076, 
9.065069, 9.063908, 9.022211, 9.054573, 9.026792, 8.98975, 8.961298, 
8.915039, 8.93357, 8.979879, 9.053955, 9.108225), X3 = c(9.092103, 
8.975852, 9.118049, 9.064759, 9.069596, 9.0599, 9.059893, 9.04653, 
9.002854, 9.036752, 9.007653, 8.968852, 8.940021, 8.891566, 8.910977, 
8.959485, 9.037077, 9.095866), X4 = c(9.095575, 8.97669, 9.116779, 
9.06228, 9.067227, 9.057312, 9.057304, 9.037841, 8.993176, 9.027841, 
8.998083, 8.958403, 8.929383, 8.87983, 8.89968, 8.949287, 9.028638, 
9.089687), X5 = c(8.712932, 8.589395, 8.697863, 8.644162, 8.648045, 
8.631554, 8.627667, 8.612026, 8.568135, 8.601243, 8.582759, 8.554589, 
8.52482, 8.482284, 8.506829, 8.542759, 8.619769, 8.689999), X6 = c(8.434263, 
8.308453, 8.396236, 8.346351, 8.350531, 8.330447, 8.324888, 8.313128, 
8.272898, 8.305936, 8.296262, 8.277004, 8.247676, 8.212734, 8.241364, 
8.268976, 8.345336, 8.422634), X7 = c(8.336248, 8.210243, 8.291891, 
8.245112, 8.249981, 8.229292, 8.223777, 8.213829, 8.176592, 8.21018, 
8.203927, 8.188092, 8.159478, 8.12425, 8.154651, 8.180216, 8.261256, 
8.341228), X8 = c(8.273279, 8.1353, 8.225183, 8.178188, 8.182844, 
8.155566, 8.155586, 8.145378, 8.107947, 8.141237, 8.129704, 8.114724, 
8.086003, 8.054416, 8.085064, 8.109359, 8.186472, 8.273313), 
    X9 = c(8.191452, 8.038108, 8.139739, 8.093593, 8.098358, 
    8.063096, 8.070529, 8.060409, 8.023834, 8.057133, 8.039449, 
    8.02588, 7.997401, 7.973722, 8.004988, 8.028113, 8.098592, 
    8.193915), X10 = c(8.221355, 8.077147, 8.161721, 8.108735, 
    8.113671, 8.087388, 8.08849, 8.046466, 7.996082, 8.016449, 
    8.016074, 7.999181, 7.970623, 7.939173, 7.968862, 8.002119, 
    8.078266, 8.169324), X11 = c(8.2263, 8.078335, 8.161404, 
    8.112908, 8.117761, 8.092432, 8.092793, 8.054483, 7.992561, 
    7.990581, 7.996326, 7.978963, 7.950399, 7.912756, 7.942222, 
    7.97596, 8.052297, 8.131317), X12 = c(8.207767, 8.051721, 
    8.135504, 8.08867, 8.093407, 8.063494, 8.063692, 8.035332, 
    7.972779, 7.962561, 7.966783, 7.951584, 7.925428, 7.886104, 
    7.920345, 7.95155, 8.02782, 8.100873), X13 = c(8.181, 8.016, 
    8.101, 8.054, 8.059, 8.023, 8.02, 8.005, 7.947, 7.935, 7.935, 
    7.923, 7.9, 7.861, 7.901, 7.929, 8.006, 8.076)), row.names = c(NA, 
18L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Could you provide in your question input data for the plot ? dput(yield)

Comment: Hi Michael Welcome to Stack Overflow. The folks here would be able to help you more easily if they had access to your data. Using a picture of your data rather than text means we can't cut and paste and would have to manually transcribe all 216 cells, which no-one is going to do. You can edit your question with the output of `dput(df)` (where`df` is your data frame) for a much better chance of a useful answer.

Comment: Hi Allan and Waldi, not really sure on how I will upload the data, thought a pop up will appear where I can upload the data

Comment: just edit the output of `dput(yields)` into your question (inside code-tags), and you'll be fine

Comment: Michael, I've done it for you.

Comment: Thank You...really appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get a similar look using `persp` in base R:

```r
persp(yield$Date, 1:13, as.matrix(yield[-1]), 
      phi = 30, theta = 120, col = "gray95", ltheta = 40, lphi= 90, shade = 0.5)
```

[image]

And there are many parameters you can adjust to get the look you want:

```r
persp(lubridate::mday(yield$Date), 1:13, as.matrix(yield[-1]), 
      phi = 45, theta = 50, col = "#FFFFC6", ltheta = 180, lphi= 30, 
      shade = 0.8, xlab = "Date", ylab = "y", zlab = "yield", 
      ticktype = "detailed", zlim = c(6, 10))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much :)

Comment: Hi Allan, how will you solve this? Error in persp.default(yielder2$Date, 1:25, as.matrix(yielder2[-1]), phi = 45,  : increasing 'x' and 'y' values expected

Comment: @Michael make sure your data is sorted according to your `yield2$Date` column, and that the values in `yield2$Date` are all increasing. Also, make sure they are in a numeric format rather than a character format (try `as.POSIXct(yield2$Date)` or `lubridate::yday(yield2$Date)`)

Comment: Thank yo sou much, also is there a way to not have it in a box, I have 2000*25 data in the z matrix, how can I make it more rectangular than a square? I tried changing the theta etc for days, but it always seems to be box like

Comment: For more clarity, how do I make it rectangular like the picture I attached